Sometimes when transformers import on windows it throws an error "Failed to import transformers.models.clip.processing_clip"
Transformers lib works really strangely. From run to run of my application sometimes transformers import throws an exception. As you can see it mentions that the error happens because of inability to open libopencore and it's not always libopencore. So the problem is not with missing this lib. I don't quite understand what does this hash mean in lib libopencore-amrwb-0-ca4ab8f34423aa96c6f93b9031e00e77.dll, but the library itself exists in the system. Additionally, mention that it throws on any import from transwormers. And sometimes it just works and doesn't throw any error.
Environment:
Python version 3.8.19
Transformers version 4.46.3 (I also tried on 4.45.1)
Error:
Exception has occurred: RuntimeError
Failed to import transformers.models.clip.processing_clip because of the following error (look up to see its traceback):
Error loading libopencore-amrwb-0-ca4ab8f34423aa96c6f93b9031e00e77.dll; The operation completed successfully.
OSError: Error loading libopencore-amrwb-0-ca4ab8f34423aa96c6f93b9031e00e77.dll; The operation completed successfully.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

  File "C:\Users\soild\Desktop\Projects\python\shorts\src\generators\pixels_video.py", line 7, in <module>
    from transformers import CLIPProcessor, CLIPModel
  File "C:\Users\soild\Desktop\Projects\python\shorts\src\scenes\background_video.py", line 8, in <module>
    from src.generators.pixels_video import generate_video
  File "C:\Users\soild\Desktop\Projects\python\shorts\src\scenes\generate.py", line 2, in <module>
    from src.scenes.background_video import generate_background_video_clip
  File "C:\Users\soild\Desktop\Projects\python\shorts\src\shorts.py", line 17, in <module>
    from src.scenes.generate import generate_scene_clip
  File "C:\Users\soild\Desktop\Projects\python\shorts\main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from src.shorts import run
RuntimeError: Failed to import transformers.models.clip.processing_clip because of the following error (look up to see its traceback):
Error loading libopencore-amrwb-0-ca4ab8f34423aa96c6f93b9031e00e77.dll; The operation completed successfully.


